# Error in function return using python

Tags: python, function, return

def random_model_predictions(droping, features):
    # Fitting a model

```
df_telecom_train, df_telecom_test = train_test_split(droping, test_size=0.25)

############## Random Forest Classifier ##############


# Set up our RandomForestClassifier instance and fit to data

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=30)
clf = clf.fit(df_telecom_train[features], df_telecom_train["Churn"])
print(clf)

# Make predictions

prediction1 = clf.predict(df_telecom_test[features])
print(prediction1)

probs = clf.predict_proba(df_telecom_test[features])
print(probs)

# Accuracy

score1 = clf.score(df_telecom_test[features], df_telecom_test["Churn"])
print("Accuracy: ", score1)

# Confusion matrix

confusion_matrix1 = pd.DataFrame(
    confusion_matrix(df_telecom_test["Churn"], prediction1),
    columns=["Predicted False", "Predicted True"],
    index=["Actual False", "Actual True"]
)
print(confusion_matrix1)

return df_telecom_test

return df_telecom_train

return probs

return clf
```

def logistic_model_prediction(df_telecom_train, features, df_telecom_test):

```
#############Logistic Regression############

# Import Library

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Create logistic regression object

model2 = LogisticRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets and check score

model2.fit([features], df_telecom_train["Churn"])
score2 = model2.score(df_telecom_train[features], df_telecom_train["Churn"])
print("Accuracy: ", score2)

# Equation coefficient and Intercept

print('Coefficient: \n', model2.coef_)
print('Intercept: \n', model2.intercept_)

# Predict Output

prediction2 = model2.predict(df_telecom_test[features])
print(prediction2)

# Confusion matrix

confusion_matrix2 = pd.DataFrame(
    confusion_matrix(df_telecom_test["Churn"], prediction2),
    columns=["Predicted False", "Predicted True"],
    index=["Actual False", "Actual True"]
)
print(confusion_matrix2)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    df_telecom_test, df_telecom_train, probs, clf = 
    random_model_predictions(droping, features)
    logistic_model_prediction(df_telecom_train, features, df_telecom_test)

While im using 2 or more return type , it is showing this type of error

ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only

Comment: try: `out2 = removing_outliers()` in `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `out2` is undefined in `if __name__ == "__main__":` because you don't save the returned value from `removing_outliers()`. So change to

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     out2 = removing_outliers()
     removing_unwanted_columns(out2)
```

and it should be fine

Comment: please help me out for the above query

Comment: This is a complete new question. Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Also provide the full traceback of the error.